# How can I get the value of element which inside of an Arralyst in my JSP with JSTL tag?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I wanted to get the value of each element which are inside of ArrayList which has been passed to JSP as a request.setAttribute.

When i write the next code I can get the value of each element wihtin the ArraList:

```
  <table border="1">
  <c:forEach var="item"  items="${ListCompanies}">
  <td><b><c:out value="${item.string2}"/></b></td>
  <td><b><c:out value="${item.string3}"/></b></td>
  </c:forEach>
  </table>
```

However, I dont know how i can get the value directlly, with out foreach operation

Something like that:

```
<c:out value="${ListCompanies.string2}"/>
```

Could somebody tell me how can I manage c:out to get value from elements?

Comment: Try `${ListCompanies.get(i).string2}` where `i` stands for the index of the item you want to display

Comment: Thanks a lot it works, have you any link where I can find more documentation aboout it.

Comment: it's how you access elements in a List in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
<c:out value="${ListCompanies[0].string2}" />
```

OR

```
<c:out value="${ListCompanies[1].string3}" />
```